# How to force Mac OSX machine to route through default gateway for same subnet?

Tags: networking, routing

I have a problem like in [Mac OS X machine can’t reach other servers on the LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/977650/mac-os-x-machine-can-t-reach-other-servers-on-the-lan/978007#978007) which requires me to go through the default Gateway to access a machine on the same subnet.

Why can't Mac do this?

I just need to force the Mac to go through the gateway for a specific route. But no matter what, it refuses to do that.

I tried deleting each of the routes individually, then as a group (e.g. link #8), and adding a specific  route to the routing table with `route -n add -net $NET $GW`. Still just keeps asking ARP for the route endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do exactly, that, but this time, add the -hopcount parameter to set network priority. The lower the "hopcount", the sooner mac looks to this route in its routing table. Without "hopcount", your router will go to the pre-existing rule for the subnet route before the route you added, and the route you added will be ineffective.

`route -n add -net $NET $GW -hopcount 0`

Example:

`route -n add -net 192.168.1.69/255 192.168.1.1 -hopcount 0`